# Curl function is not working?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch a data from a site using curl method. Before i can able to get data by using curl.Recently client taken ssl certificate for that site from then onwards i can't able to get the data using curl. But when i try the URL in browser i can able to see data. Can any one tell me why it is not working.did i need to try in some another way.
Below is my code

```
// create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://qa.myhealth.today/myhealth-portal/nirvahak/public/validateSessionttt?username=pavithra@gmail.com");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);  
  $output=json_decode($output);
     print_r($output);
```

Comment: Did you check the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option?

Comment: yep i tried it.but no luck

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 fixes:
1) SSL certified websites do not trust any non-SSL requests. So, we need to win trust of SSL enabled client.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

2) Provide him the security certificate.

Go the the respective site. Save the SSL certificate and pass the certificate path to the CURL request.

So, the final code should be:

```
// create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://qa.myhealth.today/myhealth-portal/nirvahak/public/validateSessionttt?username=pavithra@gmail.com";

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");
    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);  
  $output=json_decode($output);
     print_r($output);
```

Detailed instructions on how to do it are place [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/):

Comment: still same i did not get any out put

Answer (score 0):

Set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**

```
1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate. 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).
```

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**

```
FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php